# Deriving formula for variance

Tags: solution-verification, variance, standard-deviation

I am trying to derive the simplified variance formula and am abit stuck on a part of the proof:

$$  \hspace{-7em} \sum_{i=0}^n (x_i-\mu)^2 f(x_i) = \sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2 f(x_i) - \mu^2 $$
$$ = \sum_{i=0}^n (x_i-\mu)^2 f(x_i)$$
$$ \hspace{3em} = \sum_{i=0}^n (x_i^2 -2x_i\mu + \mu^2) f(x_i)$$
$$ \hspace{10em}= \sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2 f(x_i) - \sum_{i=0}^n 2x_i\mu f(x_i) + \sum_{i=0}^n \mu^2 f(x_i)$$
$$ \hspace{9em}= \sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2 f(x_i) - 2\mu\sum_{i=0}^n x_i f(x_i) + n \mu^2 f(x_i)$$
$$ \hspace{5em}= \sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2 f(x_i) - 2\mu^2 + n \mu^2 f(x_i)$$
$$ [ n f(x_i) = 1 ? ] $$
$$ \hspace{3em}= \sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2 f(x_i) - 2\mu^2 + \mu^2$$
$$ = \sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2 f(x_i) - \mu^2$$

I am not sure where I am going wrong with this derivation and can't find the derivation. It seems to follow that $nf(x_i) = 1$ but don't know how to make sense of it. Is this correct?
If you could steer me in the right direction, I would be grateful.

Comment: You should add and index $i$ in your summation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sum_{x=0}^n \mu^2 f(x)$ should equal $\mu^2 \sum_{x=0}^n f(x) = \mu^2$, not $n\mu^2 f(x)$, which doesn't make sense since the sum is over $x$.

Comment: Oh okay thanks. I thought that it was summing up $\mu^2 f(x)$ n times... but does that mean that  $\sum_{x=0}^{n} f(x)$  = 1?

Comment: @jackw11111 Based on the very first quantity that you start with, I am assuming $f$ is the probability mass function PMF of some distribution, which would satisfy $\sum_x f(x)=1$. But you should check for yourself whether that is true or not, since you didn't provide any context.

Comment: ahh yep that was it, I forgot the total distribution is 1. Thanks for your help.